# Why is my mongoDB hosting uri settings for mongoid.yml not working correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I'm currently using the following settings (**which does not work**) in my mongoid.yml and i've correctly added the `MONGOLAB_URI` environmental variable to my heroku environment:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      another:
        uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

I also tried the following which **does not work**:

```
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

This also **does not work**:

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```

I'm getting the following error on the heroku push:

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
       There is a configuration error with the current mongoid.yml.
       Problem:
       No database provided for session configuration: :default.
       Summary:
       Each session configuration must provide a database so Mongoid knows where the default database to persist to. What was provided was: {"another"=>{"uri"=>nil}}.
       Resolution:
       If configuring via a mongoid.yml, ensure that within your :default section a :database value for the session's default database is defined.
       Example:
       \_\_development:
       \_\_\_\_sessions:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_default:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_database: my_app_db
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_hosts:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_- localhost:27017
       There is a configuration error with the current mongoid.yml.
       Problem:
       No database provided for session configuration: :default.
       Summary:
       Each session configuration must provide a database so Mongoid knows where the default database to persist to. What was provided was: {"another"=>{"uri"=>nil}}.
       Resolution:
       If configuring via a mongoid.yml, ensure that within your :default section a :database value for the session's default database is defined.
       Example:
       \_\_development:
       \_\_\_\_sessions:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_default:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_database: my_app_db
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_hosts:
       \_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_- localhost:27017
       Asset precompilation completed (15.47s)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  I've followed the mongoid.org instructions:

```
http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html
```

I am using **mongoid 3.0.0.rc**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] = ds053681.mongolab.com:97321

production:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts: 
        - <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
      database: testapp_production
      username: testappuser
      password: testpassword
```

Comment: what is the value of ENV['MONGOLAB_URI']?

Comment: I've changed some items for security purposes but this is how it looks like: `mongodb://testappuser:testpassword@ds053681.mongolab.com:97321/testapp_production`

Comment: I am using rails 4 along mongoid 4 and the setup worked for me with a minor change. In the hosts: value I pasted directly the host from the ENV variable you're declaring above. See the way in this gist https://gist.github.com/cesc1989/30fc3035a404347bc48a

Comment: Hi, what if I need to combine 2 env together? In my case, it is mongoid.yml need to specify host in hostname:port format, I've tried different combinations to no avail <%= ENV['hostname']:ENV['port'] %> or put in 2 separate <%= ENV['hostname'] %>: <%= ENV['port'] %>

Comment: use this <%= ENV['hostname'] %>:<%= ENV['port'] %> without space between colon and port variable

Answer (score 10):

abhas's example didn't work for me. This is what finally worked:

```
production:   
  sessions:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URI'] %>
      options:
        skip_version_check: true
        safe: true
```

Comment: This is what the help page in Heroku tells to do but it doesn't work.

Comment: Copy pasting from this answer won't work due to a mishap in the environment variable name. It should be `MONGOHQ_URI` and not `MONGOHQ_URL`.

Apart from that, this is how passing mongodb URIs (e.g. mongodb://user:password@host:port/db?params) to mongoid works as this time of writing.

Comment: I changed `MONGOHQ_URL` to `MONGOHQ_URI`.

Hopefully that's correct. I haven't used this for a while

Answer (score 2):

From https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab#mongoid-5

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGOLAB_URI'] %>
```